# How to communicate between Edge-in-Edge-mode and Edge-in-IE-mode?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have got a legacy system with a web page A which calls some other web page B.
When the web page B is closed, the web page A must be refreshed, it has to read some stuff from the database which has been changed by B.

Until now, this is done by calling some function on page A when B is closed, via JavaScript.
The function on page B is something like this:

```
function goBack() { 
    window.opener.RefreshStuff();   <--- Calls RefreshStuff on page A 
    window.close();
}
```

This works well.

From now on,  page A shall run in Edge-in-IE-mode and page B shall run in Edge-in-Edge-mode.
Edge-in-IE-mode is running in another process than Edge-in-Edge-mode.
Therefore in the function goBack, the window.opener is not known anymore and the function goBack does not work anymore.

I need some way to communicate between Javascript in page B, which runs in Edge-in-Edge-mode and Javascript in page A which runs in Edge-in-IE-mode.

Can you help me?

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Comment: @Xudong Peng: Thank you! 
I am trying to get this to work for a week now. But it seems, the cookie sharing between Edge and IE doesn't do at all. 

Why? I am out of wits. It might be that it's caused by KB5010415 lacking on my system.   But I cannot install KB5010415 on my system. It just says "Cannot install this package on your system".   I tried to find a solution for this but to no avail.  I am at Win 10 ver 21H2   19044.1645.  
The MS page about KB5010415 says, it is fitting to 19042.1566, 19043.1566 and 19044.1566. maybe I cannot install it because I am at 19044.1645!?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Edge and Edge IE mode actually run different browsers, so you can't get a handle to the IE window from Edge.

You can try sharing cookies between Edge and IE, it may work for you, it needs to be configured through group policy, please refer to this document: [Configure IE mode policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies).

Finally, set the `source-engine="Both"` attribute in the sites.xml file to share the cookie between Edge and IE of the stie you need. Just refer to this doc: [Cookie sharing between Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-add-guidance-cookieshare#updated-schema-elements).